# Could not pull image - caused by: failed to register layer: error creating overlay mount to var/lib/docker/overlay2 :too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

We are facing one issue related to the IoT Edge Module pull in one of the hardware. The Gateway cannot pull all the edge modules as per the deployment manifest file. While downloading some modules, we see the error below in the IoT Edge runtime logs.

**`Could not pull image XXXXXX/YYYY:6.0.0-amd64`**

```
\<4\>2022-03-28T08:56:44Z \[WARN\] - 
caused by failed to register layer: 
error creating overlay mount to var/lib/docker/overlay2/24593016a6b6bf0eaf6543d5ec82d94244d5fcb6d25e3be62ed0da70761daacd/merged: 
too many levels of symbolic links
```

IoT Edge runtime version: 1.1.6

What's the cause for this error and how to recover from it when the devices are installed at sites during production?

We are not expecting any errors while IoT Edge modules are being pulled as per the deployment manifest file. All the modules should be pulled and running.

Comment: I've seen this before, and it seems to be a Docker issue. Have you tried the steps in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/640895/why-do-some-host-volumes-in-docker-containers-give-the-error-too-many-levels-of)?

Comment: In Iot Edge Github Repo there was a similar issue reported: https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/2908

Answer (score 0):

See below for my resolution; not sure if this will work for you.

#### Specifications

- **Hardware:** Jetson Nano
- **O/S:** Ubuntu 18.04
- **Package:** `nvidia-jetpack`
- **Version:** 4.6-b199
- **Architecture:** arm64
- **Iotedge version:** 1.2
- **Iotedge Agent:** 1.1.12.53348281

#### Background

I am experiencing the same issue on one (1) of our IoTEdge modules that is running a custom base image. I have checked the base image and it is valid and has not been updated. Also, this same Image/Module is running without issue on 13 other almost identical devices. Overall running nine modules on these machines (includes edgeAgent & edgeHub).

When I inspect the edgeAgent Logs I see the following errors:

```
Could not create module EnergyCalc
Apr 11 10:31:37 agl-a-f2-h2-u001 aziot-edged[32020]: 2022-04-11T14:31:37Z [WARN] -         caused by: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/8c5855e126f9b652d63bf02f293b2382767077eacb00490bd754db0d0c4085c7-init/merged: no such file or directory
```

This device did experience a "disk" full scenario. This issue was resolved and then I have uninstalled/reinstalled IoTEdge several times without resolution. Created/Deployed a new image (EnergyCalc2) of the same module on a test machine-works perfectly—however when I deploy to this machine, same problem exists.

#### Brute force method

- Stopped/Removed IoTEdge, Moby-cli, Moby-Engine
- Deleted `/var/lib/docker` directory:

  ```
  rm -r /var/lib/docker
  ```
- Re-installed Moby-Engine, IoTEdge

I would venture there is something in the docker configuration that is causing the problem; I did not had a chance to investigate fully.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete `/var/lib/docker`

   ```
   sudo rm -r /var/lib/docker
   ```
2. Install the specific Docker version from the `apt-cache` policy `docker-ce` candidate list:

   ```
   apt-cache madison docker-ce
   ```
3. Choose the version and insert it in the code below:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install docker-ce=<VERSION_STRING> docker-ce-cli=<VERSION_STRING> containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
   ```
4. Install docker again